# Add a YTD column in SAS

Tags: sas

This is my imported table in SAS

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaDtr.png)

I want to create a new column titled YTD that sums the months of the year. The new table should look like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FE8So.png)

It would be idea if the code was able to accommodate new months moving forward as well.

I do realize that this data set is not ideally structured, but this is what I have to work with.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site.  Please paste table details directly in as text, not as images.  Also, please add what code you've written so far, and if you haven't attempted a solution please do so, to give us the best chance to help you.  Thanks!

Comment: How to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: How to create a reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Reeza  You can use the shortcut [ ask ] , btw.  And [ mcve ].  ([ask] and [mcve])

Answer (score 0):

For the data structure imaged you can create a view that performs a sum of all numeric variables

```
data want / view=want;
  set have;
  YTD = sum (of _numeric_);
run;
```

Comment: Hi Richard; I've downvoted, because we encourage users to not answer questions that do not follow the site's guidelines, or it encourages further similar questions. I encourage you to hold off answering until a user has brought the question at least mostly in line (for example, providing data in text).